# C for loop with integers

Tags: c, for-loop

I am following the book Let us C and the following code has been shown as being perfectly correct:

```
for ( i < 4 ; j = 5 ; j = 0 ) 
    printf ( "%d", i ) ;
```

But in the Turbo C it gives 3 warnings:

> Code has no effect. Possibly incorrect assignment. 'j' is assigned a
>   value that is never used.

Comment: It's not "perfectly correct" at all, it's completely bogus. Please consider changing books (or looking for errata).

Comment: what are the 3 warnings you getting..

Comment: its a valid `C` code, but meaningless, useless. Also, `j = 5` causes infinite loop

Comment: **Don't** use `Let us C`, read [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The warnings are correct. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If the book is making the point that this code is allowed by the C standard, then it is correct. This code does not violate any rule of the C standard, provided that `i` and `j` have previously been declared correctly (and `printf` too, by including `#include <stdio.h>`).

However, nobody would actually write code like this, because it is not useful. That is why the compiler is issuing a warning, because the code is technically allowed but is probably not what a programmer would intend.

If the book is claiming that this code is useful in some way, then it is probably a typographical error. It is certainly wrong. If the book has more than a few errors like this, you should discard it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your book want to teach you with this example, but AFAIK a for loop should always be in the form

```
for ( init; check; next ) {
    /* do something */
}
```

where *init* initialize what you're going to use, *check* check if it should stop or continue and *next* perform some kind of action. It is the same as

```
init;
while ( check ) {
    /* do something */
    next;
}
```

Therefore you are getting the warning because:

- *Code has no effect* is referred to *i < 4*. As you can see in the *while* form, this comparison isn't used in any way, therefore it has no effect.
- *Possibly incorrect assignment.* is refereed to *j = 5* cause you're making a check of an assignment witch will always evaluate to the value assigned (in this case 5)
- *'j' is assigned a value that is never used* as it says, 'j' is never used, as you print the 'i' in this example.

Probably what the book wants to do is *for ( i = 5; i < 5; i++ )*.
And probably what you need to do is using a better book.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid C code but it's pretty much meaningless.  This will not initialize the loop properly and trigger an infinite loop.  Loops look something like

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

The first statement is the initializer, the second stipulates the end case, and the last is the increment.  I would get rid of that book

Comment: ... And what about the warnings OP asked about? - That is the Q

Comment: I was trying to lead him to that by pointing out that his loop while syntactically correct, is probably not going to give the behavior the author intended.  Where a loop similar the one shown above will is a much more standard use of loops

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct but infinite loop,
the correct way to instantiate a for loop is

```
int i ;
for(i = 0; i< [variable or number];i++){
printf("%d",i);
}
```

the code you wrote is meaningless and you can't do anything with that code, actually it print the value of i infinite time because it never change.
The only thing we know about i is less then 4. Probably the output is always the same number.